# Issue deleting IDs greater than 1000

Tags: java, web-services, rest, jersey

I've stumbled on a rather strange issue. Searching has not gave any answers so I thought to ask it here...

I'm creating a program that communicates with a webservice (rest). On the client side, I have this method which deletes a sample:

```
public void remove(int id) throws UniformInterfaceException {
    webResource.path(java.text.MessageFormat.format("{0}", new Object[]{id})).delete();
}
```

On the server side:

```
@DELETE
@Path("{id}")
public void remove(@PathParam("id") Integer id) {
    System.out.println("delete sample id = " + id);
    super.remove(super.find(id));
}
```

Now, this seems to work with all IDs < 1000 (id is shown in the output). As soon as it is above 1000, there seem to be a thousand seperators at work for some reason? This results in following error at the client side:

```
com.sun.jersey.api.client.UniformInterfaceException: DELETE http://localhost:8080/myname/webresources/entities.samples/1,261 returned a response status of 404 Not Found
```

Why does it use 1,261 in the URI instead of 1261? Or am I making any silly mistake somewhere?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: why don't you just call String.valueOf(id), MessageFormat seems to be an overhead here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that the [MessageFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html) class uses the locale to format numbers. From the javadoc (under the subformat created column of the table at the top), "NumberFormat.getIntegerInstance(getLocale())". This includes a thousands separator for some locales. Consider the following:

```
java> MessageFormat.format("{0}", new Object[]{Integer.valueOf(999)})
String res0 = "999"

java> MessageFormat.format("{0}", new Object[]{Integer.valueOf(1000)})
String res1 = "1,000"
```

You could optionally change from using MessageFormat in this case to Integer.toString:

```
java> Integer id = 999
Integer id = 999

java> id.toString()
String res3 = "999"

java> id = 1000
Integer id = 1000

java> id.toString()
String res4 = "1000"
```